# trouble saving word documents on macbook

Tags: macos, ms-office

Sometimes, when I create a document on Microsoft word I have issues when trying to save the file on my Mac.

For example, I type out an entire document titled HEALTH. The file will save no problem first try. However, when I go in and edit the document HEALTH and try to re-save the file, a notification pops up saying "replace the file" I click yes. The word doc then closes, and then re-opens on my screen by itself within seconds. I then click save as, replace file, and so fourth. The document will continue to open and I could literally click "replace" 100 times, but it is not replacing.. I then tried to click "don't replace" or "don't save as" thinking it must have saved after those multiple attempts. Nope, file is gone, it is deleted, no option to recover file. WHY IS THIS HAPPENING !! I see no other people with this similar issue, but it happens to me quite often when I create a new document, and then try to edit it at another time.. My only solution has been copy and pasting the file into Pages and saving it there..

Comment: Where are you saving it - locally on your Mac or online in your OneDrive/Office365 account?  Check on *File* > *Save As* if you aren't sure.

Comment: As a temporary work-a-round, do save as and give the file a new name or new folder. What version of word are you using?  I experience some like what you report in word 2011.